# I’m trying to turn two decimal numbers into floating point numbers, divide them and show the result in 16 bit assembly

Tags: visual-studio-code, assembly

I’m trying to turn two decimal numbers into floating point numbers, divide them and show the result in 16 bit assembly for a class project without using the floating point unit. I have no idea why whenever I run it prints an infinite loop of weird symbols.

.model small
.stack 200h
.data
decimal_number1 dw 1234
decimal_number2 dw 5678
output_string db "Result: $"

.code start:

```
mov ax, [decimal_number1]
mov bx, ax
shr bx, 8                 
and ax, 0FFh              
shl ax, 8                 
or ax, bx              
mov dx, ax

mov ax, [decimal_number2]
mov bx, ax
shr bx, 8                 
and ax, 0FFh              
shl ax, 8                 
or ax, bx            

mov ax, dx              
xor dx, dx                
div ax                    

mov ah, 09h               
lea dx, [output_string]   
int 21h                   

mov si, 4
```

print_digits:
xor dx, dx
mov cx, 10
div cx
add dl, '0'
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
dec si
test ax, ax
jnz print_digits

```
mov ax, 4Ch             
int 21h
```

end start

Comment: You need to save and restore register AX around the INT 21H calls.